# Payoff of option

Tags: options, mathematics

Consider the payoff $g(S_T)$ shown the figure:

[image]

I believe the payoff represented as a linear combination of the payoffs of some options with different strike and same maturity $T$ is $$g(S_T) =   (2K - S_T)_{+} - (K - S_T)_{+}$$

I am not exactly sure this is correct, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just plug $S_T=0$ in your equation to see that it does not give $g(S_T=0)=K$ as it should... How can you not be sure that this is incorrect Morgan? The payoff is equivalent to: long put struck at $2K$ and short put struck at $K$ (put spread).

Comment: I know what the strategy is but I guess a classmate of mine mistakenly told me that $g(S_T = 0) = 0$ and the $-K$ is that amount of cash we put up for the position.

Comment: If you know then why ask?

Comment: Well, I just wanted to check if it was right. My professor tends to make many mistakes in his lecture notes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of question, you basically need only to write the payoff with certain indicator functions. In particular, for the above payoff, we have that
\begin{align*}
\textrm{Payoff} &= K\, 1_{S_T \le K} + (2K-S_T)\,1_{K < S_T \le 2K}\\
&=K\, 1_{S_T \le K} + (2K-S_T)\big(1_{S_T \le 2K} - 1_{S_T \le K} \big)\\
&=(2K-S_T)\,1_{S_T \le 2K} - (K-S_T)1_{S_T \le K}\\
&=(2K-S_T)^+ - (K-S_T)^+.
\end{align*}